# Why is the MPMoviePlayerController  not pausing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a viewContoller holding MPMoviePlayerController.
Everything is working fine but just one thing - pause.
in the viewDidLoad I load the Video and even if I call pause on it still continues to play.

But if I capture double-tap or say a button click once the video is playing the video pauses on a call to pause.

What to do to make the video paused as it loads ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What to do to make the video paused as it loads ?

Try: `[yourPlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];`

Comment: Thanks. 

Such a small thing! I tried searching  a notification that tells that video has loaded or not and so many weird things.


IMPORTANT : Dont Copy Paste ! it should be setShouldAutoplay.
p is small. I copied and then scratched my head for 15min that why isnt the object recognizing the selector when the documentation says  so as well.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. I wasn't sure, did this one straight out of my head ... Sorry for that. (This reminds me of the discussion: `addSubView:`).